# Find header in range and return last value in column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How would you search in a range for a particular header and then return the last value in that column?

eg return "10" from the "Bananas" column in the following:

```
| Oranges | Apples | Bananas |
| 34      | 45     | 42      |
| 36      | 56     | 34      |
| 76      | 53     | 10      |
```

The size of the range (number of rows and columns) is unknown.

I can use `=match("Bananas",a1:a3)` to find column number in the range (3 in this instance), but need to translate that to a reference (eg `c:c`) and then use something like `=INDEX(c:c, COUNTA(c:c), 1)` to find the last value.

Comment: Is there always the same number of rows in each column or might there be more rows in "Bananas" than "Apples"?

Comment: @ScottCraner There will always be an equal number of rows in each column and there will be no blanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try if the number of rows are always the same:

```
=HLOOKUP("Bananas",A:AZ,MATCH(1E+99,A:A),FALSE)
```

If you want one that does not care if the number of rows are the same then use this:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(MID(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("Bananas",1:1,0)),2,1)&":"&MID(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("Bananas",1:1,0)),2,1)),MATCH(1E+99,INDIRECT(MID(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("Bananas",1:1,0)),2,1)&":"&MID(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("Bananas",1:1,0)),2,1))))
```

It will find "Bananas" and THEN find the last occupied cell in that column.

Comment: I don't know if this is specific to the system I'm using just now but that `1e+999` gave me an error and wanted to change to `E1+999` which is not the same thing. fwiw, I didn't have any problem with `1E+99`.

Comment: Yeah, 99 zeroes is probably enough in any event.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you - can you explain how this works? My data is (for example) in the range A15:I27.

Comment: It is like a VLOOKUP, but horizontal.  So it looks in the first row of the range for "Bananas" then it returns the value that is in row returned by the match function. The match tries to find the large number 1 with 99 zeros, since it cant, it finds the last cell with numbers in it.

Comment: @ScottCraner Your first formula (for same number of rows) works great - can this be modified to get the second to last item in the column?

Comment: @mistertaylor yes, easily just ad a `- 1` after the match function.  `=HLOOKUP("Bananas",A:AZ,MATCH(1E+99,A:A) - 1,FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

If you have the columns named, it works as I described before. 
[image]

Cell E1
`=INDEX(Oranges:Oranges, COUNTA(Oranges:Oranges), 1)`
Cell E2
`=INDEX(Apples:Apples, COUNTA(Apples:Apples), 1)`
Cell E3
`=INDEX(Bananas:Bananas, COUNTA(Bananas:Bananas), 1)`

Comment: Unfortunately, the columns aren't named - the data is across multiple sheets which are auto-generated by a third party - I'm attempting to automate collation of the data.

Comment: This is a great approach.